# Notifications for incoming text messages using service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am struck with my issue from days. Actually what I want to do is to create a notification service to provide the user alerts even the user is out of the application. And that service should check for incoming messages in every 5 minutes. And notifications should exactly same the way of notification inbox style in notification drawer. I need to call particular activity by clicking the notifications. Can anyone suggest me how to do it? Thanks for help....

Comment: you need to register a broadcastReceiver for listening about the new messages and then start a service to perform your action.

Comment: @Rohan Kandwal, Is that service runs automatically? How can we register to broadcastReceiver please provide some code..

Comment: you need not to check for the incoming message every 5 minutes. The code I provided will automatically detect any incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need get permissions to receive and read sms. That you can do in the `androidManifest.xml` using the following code:-

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.sms"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application></manifest>
```

Then you need to set your BroadcastReceiver to receive the notification of incoming SMS.

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "no message received";
    if(bundle != null){

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length;i++){

            msgs[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from Phone No: " +msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str +="\n"+"Message is: ";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str +="\n";
        }

        Log.v("Debug", str);
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

The above code will get you the SMS sender's contact number and the message that was received.

Comment: Now if you want to need a Service on SMS received then you can start a Service in `onReceive()`

Comment: @user3057567 Aside from the fact that I don't know what exactly you want in your service, I won't do your homework. SO is for helping you when you face any problems not doing your work. Try it on your own and if you face any problem, we are here to help.

Comment: @user3057567 And some FYI, if you see any answer that helped you then please upvote it and if it solved your problem then mark the answer correct. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: @user3057567 was your problem solved? If so, mark this question solved.

Comment: I would like to do the same except that my incoming messages are not SMS instead they are CAP messages received through MQTT broker (server). Will your solution apply to any incoming message or just text messages ? thanks

Comment: They should only work for SMS, I'm not even sure what CAP messages are, so can't help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured it out

Comment: Just to share a small knoweldge (which is the point of this forum), CAP is short for **Common Alert Protocol** ([here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/emergency/cap/v1.2/CAP-v1.2-os.html)) which is a standard for emergecny services such as fire fighters, medical staff and first responders. It is constructed using **XML format** but with specific mandatory fields such as sender, event, urgency, etc... . It will be included in the upcoming Mobile 5G standards. (I wish and hope this will be useful to you in future :-) )

Comment: @Suda.nese Thanks for the info and link. Might come in handy one of these days.